# Error Code: 900144 Message: The request body must contain the following parameter: '{name}'

Tags: powershell, devops

> This is the code used to generate access tokens. But I am getting this error. Error Code: 900144 Message: The request body must contain the following parameter: '{name}'

```
 
param (
    $RefreshToken,
    $tenantId,
    $clientId,
    $clientSecret
    )

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

# Azure token endpoint
$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Prepare the body of the request
$body = @{
    grant_type = "refresh_token"
    client_id = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    refresh_token = $RefreshToken
    scope = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"
}

# Prepare the headers
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

# Make the POST request
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenUrl -Method Post -Header $headers -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json)

# Output the response
$response
```

> How to resolve this error?

Comment: Are you getting error when you request token or the Post?  For Token See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token.  For Azure see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azaccesstoken?view=azps-11.0.0

Comment: When I am running the code in my local powershell env I am not getting any errors but when I am running the code in devops powershell pipeline I am getting this error

Comment: You must be using a different credential when connecting to the server.  The top of the webpage in my 1st link explains the process.  Also see following for troubleshooting : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/troubleshooting?view=azps-11.0.0